# PlotStyle in ParametricPlot3D getting applied to all curves

Tags: plotting, style

Consider

```
curves = {{x, x, 0}, {x, 2 x, 0}}
ParametricPlot3D[curves, {x, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot3D[curves, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
ParametricPlot3D[{{x, x, 0}, {x, 2 x, 0}}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

In the first two cases, neither does `ParametricPlot3D` automatically colour grade the curves nor apply the explicit `PlotSyle`.

It works as intended in the third syntax.

Why is this so?

---

Note:Doesn't occur in `Plot`,`Plot3D`,`ParametricPlot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curves = {{x, x, 0}, {x, 2 x, 0}};

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ curves, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ curves, {x, 0, 1},    PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: works but why is it needed here and not for others, say plot3D?

Comment: @lineage, not sure why.